# How I lists polymorphic with different model together in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

Here I have 3 different models 
   
1.Category
   
2.Branch
   
3.Product

The Category model has many branches, And the Branches has many different products.

And each of them has comments with polymorphic model commentable.

Here is my question. 
How can I make products' comments also can be seen in its branch view? And mixed with branches' comments sorting by updated date?

ex. 

procuct1 has comment1 updated in 5/1

branch1 has  comment2 in 5/2

and product2 has comment3 in 5/3

And in my branch1 view. I can see all the above comments in sequence.

comment1

comment2

comment3

Answer (score 0):

Using Subquery and Union will directly helps.

Assuming the Branch id is 1,

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base 
   def all_comments
     Comment.where("commentable_type IN ('Product', 'Branch') 
                   AND commentable_id in (SELECT id FROM products WHERE 
                   branch_id = ? OR ?)", self.id, self.id)
           .order("comments.updated_at ASC")
  end
end

class BranchesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @branch.all_comments
  end
end
```

Comment: What to do in branch controller? @commentable =?